# How to send external data to OnlyOffice plugin

Tags: asp.net, iframe, onlyoffice

I am developing onlyoffice plugin, which need to consume data (like reportid, session details that will be used to load data from server) from launching application.

structure of page come out like:

launching page (editor.aspx)
--  iframe 1 to load editor
-- -- ifram 2 to load plugin

Here i want to access data from editor.aspx into iframe 2 (javascript)

I tried using queryString like `window.parent.location.search` but it only can traverse till iframe 1, but not main aspx page. As i don't have control on what loads in iframe 1 it didn't work.

Also i tried  with cookies and localStorage but none worked out.

Please guide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> launching page (editor.aspx) -- iframe 1 to load editor -- -- ifram 2
>   to load plugin. Here i want to access data from editor.aspx into iframe
>   2 (javascript)

There is no way to get direct access to the iframe with editor, the only way to work with it is using [document server plugins](https://api.onlyoffice.com/plugin/basic)

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way... Having spent a **LOT** of time analysing what is going on... finally found a nice way to exchange configs between the `TOP` frame and `PLUGIN` frame with just a few lines of code leveraging the onlyoffice API - without any hacks :)

Editor Config object:

```
config: {
    "width"       : "100%",
    "height"      : "100%",
    "type"        : "desktop",
    "documentType": "text",
    "token"       : "{{token}}",
    "document"    : {
        "title"      : "{{document.name}}",
        "url"        : "{{downloadUrl}}",
    
    ...
    
    events: {
        'onReady': <application ready callback>, // deprecated
        ...
        'onInfo': function ( data ) {
            if ( data && data.data && data.data.getConfig ) {
                docEditor.serviceCommand ( 'getConfig', config.document );
            }
        }
    }
}

var docEditor = new DocsAPI.DocEditor("placeholder", config);
```

`onInfo` event will receive the request from your plugin.
Need to check the event data has `getConfig` attribute.
If it does, send back the config to the plugin.

Within your plugin's `index.html` add an inline script tag with this content:

```
// config ref
var config;

// Get ready to receive the response from TOP
window.parent.Common.Gateway.on ( 'internalcommand', ( data ) => {
    if ( data.command === 'getConfig' ) {
        config = data.data;
    }
} );

// Send custom config request to TOP
window.parent.Common.Gateway.sendInfo ( { getConfig: true } );
```

It subscribes to the `internalcommand` Gateway events which will be called by `TOP`, then kick in the communication process by calling the `sendInfo` command. Because the editor and your plugins (most likely) will be hosted on the same domain, you can access it via the `window.parent` ref.

This will download the `config.document` configuration object and store it in the plugins local `config` variable automatically - when you click on the plugin in the toolbar.

Comment: This worked like a champ, thank you!